# Swift: Handling login error states properly?

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I've been trying to find a better way to handle my error states.

Currently I have about 10 `if else` statements, which clearly is an inefficient way to handle my errors.

From what I've been able to find, it looks like enumerations are the way to go. But I havn't been able to implement it successfully.

Every example I've been able to find follow this form:

```
enum Result<T> {
    case Success(T)
    case Failure(String)
}

var result = divide(2.5, by:3)

switch result {
case Success(let quotient):
    doSomethingWithResult(quotient)
case Failure(let errString):
    println(errString)
}
```

But I don't quite see how this can work for my error states.

There's no if statements, not to mention explanation of where to implement these, and they all only have 1 "action" In the above example a println.

I have several lines of code I need to run for every error state.

Here's an example of my errorhandling for an email textfield.

```
    if textField == emailTextField {
        emailTextField.textColor = UIColor.formulaBlackColor()
        emailIcon.setTitleColor(UIColor.formulaBlackColor(), forState: .Normal)
        emailTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        if textField.text.isEmpty {
            emailIcon.setTitleColor(UIColor.formulaRedColor(), forState: .Normal)
            emailState.text = ""
            emailTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:"Email Address",
                attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.formulaRedColor()])
            showError("Please enter your email.")
        } else if emailTextField.text.isValidEmail() == false {
            emailIcon.setTitleColor(UIColor.formulaRedColor(), forState: .Normal)
            emailTextField.textColor = UIColor.formulaRedColor()
            emailState.text = ""
            showError("Please enter a valid email address")
        } else {
            emailIcon.setTitleColor(UIColor.formulaBlackColor(), forState: .Normal)
            emailState.textColor = UIColor.formulaGreenColor()
            emailState.text = ""
            hideError()
        }
    }
```

I've been trying to make an enum like this:

```
enum Login {
    case NoInternetConnection
    case NoEmail
    case InvalidEmail
    case NoPassword
    case WrongEmailOrPassword
    case Success
}
```

But I havn't found a way to make this work.

When I added a switch case, I was presented with an error "Expected Declaration",

I tried putting it in a function, and the error went away. But I havn't been able to figure out how to do anything with the cases.

```
switch Login {
case Success:println("CASE SUCCESS")
case NoEmail:println("CASE NoEmail")
}
```

Obviously I still have to implement my if statements in some way to check e.g. if the emailTextField is empty? But how can I set the case to NoEmail. And make it run several lines of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a value of that enumeration first, that you can check, like so:

```
enum Login {
    case NoInternetConnection
    case NoEmail
    case InvalidEmail
    case NoPassword
    case WrongEmailOrPassword
    case Success
}

// Here you get your result, e.g. from a function.
let loginResult = Login.Success

switch loginResult {
case let .NoInternetConnection:
    println("No internet connection")
case let .NoEmail:
    println("No email specified")
case let .InvalidEmail:
    println("Email invalid")
case let .NoPassword:
    println("No password specified")
case let .WrongEmailOrPassword:
    println("Email or password wrong")
case let .Success:
    println("Success")
}
```

Remember that there is also another way to go, which is [Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html).

In my opinion, it is always best to break such conditional chains up into several functions (see also [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)), but unfortunately Swift does not support catching exceptions, so we have to go this way.

Comment: Alright so in my if statements I'd just do something like `if textField.text.isEmpty { let loginResult = Login.NoEmail }` But how do I run multiple lines of code in the switch? Or does it just simply run all lines of code after the `:` until it's met with a new case or end of brackets?

Comment: Yes indeed it runs all lines of code after the `:` until the next case / end of braces. You can simply try it in a playground btw.

Comment: Thank you, I got it working. Had to put it in it's own function though? Didn't seem to work in textFieldDidEndEditing. But it works now :) Thank you so much!